# Validate date/time in another country, prevent delay in timezones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

How do I validate if the date of an object is going on today, preventing delay timezones.

My Ruby's app hosted in the USA and my time zone is in another country.

Ex:
List of games to be played today.

```
<% @matches.each do |m| %>
    <% if(m.date.today?) %>
        <p>This match will be played today</p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The 'if' sentence brings back the results of the matches to be played today, including upcoming games seven hours, server delay product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the date to the user's timezone.

```
m.date.in_time_zone(<user's time zone>).today?
```